# TeamCity (linux) server and MSBuild

Tags: c#, linux, msbuild, teamcity

According to other posts the way to be able to analyze Visual Studio Projects is to include MSBuild binaries on the TeamCity server itself.

Does this mean that the TeamCity server must be installed on a Windows machine?
Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

TeamCity has built agents which are responsible for the execution of build.
Therefore, you can install the server on a different machine than an agent.
So, server can be linux and build agent must be Widows.

Comment: In fact I strongly recommend that people install TeamCity onto a different PC than the build agents.

Comment: The build agent is on a separate machine. So then copying binaries is not needed?

Comment: I had the impression that these binaries must reside on the server itself

Comment: @Alix For example check [this article](http://www.danmusk.com/how-to-build-asp-net-applications-in-teamcity-with-msbuild-tools-2013-and-net-framework-4-5-sdk/) which aims to "*get a simple ASP.NET webproject to build in TeamCity, without installing Visual Studio on the build server*". This seems to indicate that you DO need to install the MSBuild binaries on the server (but not Visual Studio, ofc), which would appear to rule out Linux.

Comment: Now I'm confused, @MatthewWatson


Quote from section "Configure the TeamCity server":

_Install Microsoft Build Tools 2013_

Comment: @Alix By default TeamCity install agent and server on same machine. You need binaries on agent machine, because there is executed build.

Comment: @Alix Yes, I'm saying that it looks like you can't do it on Linux because you need to install the Microsoft Build Tools.